# Leaflet Map and IONIC 4

Tags: dictionary, leaflet, ionic4

I need to create maps on IONIC 4.
But it is not possible, because I don't have maps for IONIC 4.

So, is it possible to create a Leaflet Map on IONIC 4 for an App on Android?

Comment: You may want to be more specific, to add more details to your question. What did you try so far? What is the exact problem or obstacle? Other than that, I don't see why you shouldn't be able to Leaflet on Ionic 4.

Comment: I want create a dynamic map on IONIC 4 and add markers, I don't need directions to link markers, but I need geolocation.

Answer (score 11):

1. npm install leaflet --save
2. inside angular.json or any similar config doc of your app, add the following:

   a)

   ```
   "assets": [
         ...,
         {
           "glob": "**/*",
           "input": "./node_modules/leaflet/dist/images",
           "output": "leaflet/"
         }
       ],
   ```

   b)

   ```
   "styles": [
         ...,
         "./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"
       ],
   ```
3. Inside your component.html:

   ```
   <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
   ```
4. Inside your component.ts:

   ```
   import { Map, latLng, tileLayer, Layer, marker } from 'leaflet';

   map: Map;
   ```
5. then you can call a function like this when the DOM is loaded:

   ```
   loadmap() {
     setTimeout(() => {
       this.map = new Map('map').setView([this.lat, this.lng], 8);

       tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          // tslint:disable-next-line
         attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a 
       href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a 
       href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery 
       © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
         maxZoom: 18
       }).addTo(this.map);

     }, 50);
   }
   ```

Notice, this.lat, this.lng are my own values.

For anything else, there are the docs: https://leafletjs.com/reference-versions.html

**EDIT:**

Instead of setTimeout, I use Ionic's ionViewDidEnter().
SetTimeout was a workaround, because Angular's ngAfterViewInit() was not working for me.

Comment: Nice answer! As a side note, Ionic4 does not necessarily involve Angular.

Comment: That is true... I will try to make it more general.

Comment: If you are using a component such as tab, remember to include the following.`if (this.map) return;`

Answer (score 3):

Answer from @alex351 is very good. But I arrived into this thread from Google looking for "ionic4 leaflet broken map".

I had tiles not showing up, even with the import of leaflet.css.

It was because I wrote

```
<ion-content>
  <div id="map" style="height:400px; width: 100%;"></div>
</ion-content>
```

It seems Ionic4 css conflicts with leaflet.
You need to get the `<div>` **outside of** `<ion-content>`.

Correct is just :

```
<div id="map" style="height:400px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Hope this help someone