# How to add leaflet map plugin to ionic4 code?

Tags: leaflet, ionic4

I'm trying to implement leaflet maps in ionic apps. I refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53945625/leaflet-map-and-ionic-4). Then, I need to add new button using leaflet plugins: [easyButton](http://cliffcloud.github.io/Leaflet.EasyButton/) but failed to implement it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. in cli

   `npm install leaflet-easybutton`
2. in your *.page.ts

import 'leaflet-easybutton';

3. example:

```
const  helloPopup = L.popup().setContent('Hello World!');
L.easyButton('fa-globe', function(btn, map) {
   helloPopup.setLatLng(map.getCenter()).openOn(map);
}).addTo( this.map);
```